# How to change Letters to Numbers for numbers to be assigned with nodes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, chr

I want to know how to put say for example, A(both capital and lowercase) into the node 0 in my code but I really have no idea how. I get that there's chr but I have never used it before and I tried to read and do it and, I just can't get my head around it.

Here's my code:

```
infinity = 1000000
invalid_node = -1

class Node:
    previous = invalid_node
    distFromSource = infinity
    visited = False

def populateNetwork(fileName):

    network = []
    networkFile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in networkFile:
        network.append(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
    return network

def populateNodeTable(network, StartNode):
    nodeTable = []
    for node in network:
        nodeTable.append(Node())
    nodeTable[StartNode].distFromSource = 0
    nodeTable[StartNode].visited = True
    return nodeTable

def nearestNeighbour(network, currentNode):
    neighbours = []
    column = 0
    for node in network[currentNode]:
        if node !=0:
            neighbours.append(column)
        column +=1
    return neighbours


def tentativeDistance(neighbours, network, nodeTable, currentNode):
    for neighbour in neighbours:
        if nodeTable[neighbour].visited == False:
            tentative = nodeTable[currentNode].distFromSource + network[currentNode][neighbour]
            if tentative < nodeTable[neighbour].distFromSource:
                nodeTable[neighbour].distFromSource = tentative
                nodeTable[neighbour].previous = currentNode
                print tentative

##Testing this Function
def newNodeTable(nodeTable):
    nextNode == invalid_node
    currentIndex = 0
    nextDestination == infinity
    for node in nodeTable:
        if node.visited == False and node.distanceFromSource < nextDestination:
            nextNode = currentIndex
            nextDestination = node.distanceFromSource
        currentIndex+=1
    return nextNode

##Testing this Function
def getRoute(routePath):
    getRoutePath = []
    getRouteFile = open(routePath, "r")
    for line in getRouteFile:
        getRoutePath.append(int,line.split(">"))
    return getRoutePath

network = populateNetwork('network.txt')
nodeTable = populateNodeTable(network, 1)
neighbours=nearestNeighbour(network, 1)
tentativeDistance(neighbours, network, nodeTable, 1)

print
print "Current nodes and visited"
for node in nodeTable:
    print node.previous, node.distFromSource, node.visited

##for line in network:
##    print line
print
print "Visual representation of the network array"
for index, val in enumerate(network):
    print index, val
```

Here is my network.txt file:

```
0,2,4,1,6,0,0
2,0,0,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,0,5,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0
6,5,0,1,0,5,5
0,0,5,1,5,0,0
0,0,0,0,5,0,0
```

And my route.txt file is basically either going to be "A>G" , "a>G" or "a>g".

Answer (score 0):

You can use text

```
import string

print string.ascii_uppercase
# ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

print string.ascii_lowercase
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

print string.ascii_letters
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

char = string.ascii_uppercase[0]  # A
char = string.ascii_uppercase[1]  # B
char = string.ascii_uppercase[2]  # C

char = string.ascii_lowercase[0]  # a
char = string.ascii_lowercase[1]  # b
char = string.ascii_lowercase[2]  # c
```

Or you can use `chr(number)`

```
print chr(65 + 0) # A
print chr(65 + 1) # B
print chr(65 + 2) # C

print chr(97 + 0) # a
print chr(97 + 1) # b
print chr(97 + 2) # c
```

You can find character number using `ord(letter)`

```
print ord('A') # 65
print ord('a') # 97
```

Comment: Another question if u dont mind, i did this code: def getRoute(getRouteFile):
    getRoutePath = []
    routeFile = open(getRouteFile, "r")
    for routes in routeFile:
        getRoutePath.append(map(ord, routes.split('>')))
    return getRoutePath  ,         which worked for me. How would it be possible to use these two ascii numbers to figure out which is the least or bigger?